# Inject generic service bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have some highly repetitive code that i decided to move into an abstract class, for the sake of simplicity let's assume that the class looks like:

```
class AbstractEntityService<E extends MyEntity, REPO extends MyRepository<E>> {

      @Autowired
      private REPO repo;

      ... // methods

}
```

and I have about 10 separate classes that need this functionality
so i have

```
@Service
class MyService1 extends AbstractEntityService<MyEntity1, MyEntity1Repo> {}

@Service
class MyService2 extends AbstractEntityService<MyEntity2, MyEntity2Repo> {}

...
```

MyService1 ... MyService10 don't really do anything other than to cement the types for spring's autodetection to work.

I'm wondering if i can get away without defining them and injecting

```
@Autowired
private AbstractEntityService<MyEntity2, MyEntity2Repo> myEntity2Repo;
```

directly without defining the classes myself.

Comment: You may be able to autowire a subclass, but the concrete class has to exist, and I don't think there is any way to get Spring to create it for you. I'm curious as to what it is you are doing in the abstract class, since I have coded fairly large Spring/JPA projects, and I have never had the need for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm pretty sure you cannot.

I think the best you can do is if you create the beans yourself in a config file.

```
import javax.inject.Inject; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public MyConfic {

    @Inject MyEntity1Repo myEntity1Repo;
    @Inject MyEntity2Repo myEntity2Repo;

    @Bean(name="myEntity1Service")
    AbstractEntityService<MyEntity1, MyEntity1Repo> myEntity2Service(){
        return new AbstractEntityService<> myEntity1Service( myEntity2Repo );
    }

    @Bean(name="myEntity2Service")
    AbstractEntityService<MyEntity2, MyEntity2Repo> myEntity2Service(){
        return new AbstractEntityService<> myEntity2Service( myEntity2Repo );
    }

}
```

At least this way you don't have to create a separate subclass per entity.

Mind you, now you cannot do injection by type since *after* erasure your `myEnity1Service` you will have the same type as `myEnity2Service`: `AbstractEntityService`. Using something like

```
@Inject @Named("myEntity2Service" )
AbstractEntityService<MyEntity2, MyEntity2Repo> myEntity2Service;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the best thing I could think of as well (although you can save the name, as it will be the method name by default)

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek I like it as a reminder that you'll need to use `@Named` at the `@Inject` but I believe you are correct.

Comment: With Spring you don't even need the name as long as you have the generic type information. So the name is actually optional both on the bean and at the injection point - But I'm not sure it would work in a J2EE environment.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek isn't the generic type information erased?

Comment: I thought so too. Erasure happens at object level, but the bytecode actually has the generics information, so it can be utilized for this type of 'magic'. ```Method``` actually has a ```getGenericReturnType()``` and Spring uses this to build ```ResolvableType``` which has the correct generics information.

Comment: @ArtB, thanks, I was also thinking of something like that but i wanted spring to define everything for me.

I was hoping that there would be a possibility but i kind of assumed that there wasn't any available since we can't do that with JpaRepositories either. Most of the JpaRepositories that i defined were simply MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, ID>